# Arabic URL route using express web framework?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem getting express to render a page using an arabic url route:

```
app.get('/شقق-في-لندن', function(req, res){
    res.render('apartments');
});
```

when I try access this using the browser `localhost:5000/شقق-في-لندن` i get an error saying not found.

```
Cannot GET /%D8%B4%D9%82%D9%82-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%84%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%86
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use request `params` and check for the url like the following

```
app.get('/:arabic_url', function(req, res , next ){
  if(req.params.arabic_url !== 'شقق-في-لندن') {
    return next();
  }
  res.render('apartments');
});
```

I found A problem with my current implementation and I recommend the way @Vasan because in my impementation the order of your routes will cause an error , unexpected behaviour and redundancy.

Here is the right solution

```
app.get('/' + encodeURIComponent('شقق-في-لندن') , function(req, res){
    res.render('apartments');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

a) Write a middleware (executing before routing) that URL-decodes the UTF8 characters in URL and updates req.url
Advantage: Any subsequent middleware you write can refer to the original UTF-8 characters

Crude example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.url = decodeURI(req.url);
    next();
});
```

[OR]

b) Change route(s) to match the URL-encoded versions like so

```
app.get('/%D8%B4%D9%82%D9%82-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%84%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%86', function(req, res){
    res.render('apartments');
});
```

or more elegantly:

```
app.get('/'+encodeURIComponent('شقق-في-لندن'), function(req, res){
    res.render('apartments');
});
```